# If $m>n$, is $(m!)^n or\ (n!)^m$?

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, factorial

m and n are two positive numbers and m>n. Which one is greater?
$(m!)^n or\ (n!)^m$

I solved this question when m and n are natural numbers. I am wondering if there is any suggestion for the question when m and n are positive real numbers.

Comment: Do you know how to define $n!$ if $n \not\in \mathbb{N}$ with the Gamma function?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you defining $m!$ for real numbers using the gamma function?

Comment: Yes, It is an integral.

Comment: Now, show it for rationals, and then by continuity finish the problem.

Comment: By comparing Cesaro's mean it ca be done for natural numbers. How can we come up with the reault for real numbers.

Comment: @Keon Focus on the rationals first.

Comment: It seems (m!)^n>(n!)^m even for real numbers.This is only an example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282.1%21%29%5E%282.09%29%3E%282.09%29%21%5E2.1  We also know Gamma function is stricly  positive function and increasing.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind here is Stirling. At least that should work for $m,n$ large enough

Comment: My mentor suggested using log of gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere below $z$ is assumed to be a positive real number.

Let start with [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#The_log-gamma_function):
$$
\log\Gamma(1+z)=\log z+\log\Gamma(z)
=-\gamma z+\sum_{k\ge1}\left[\frac zk-\log\left(1+\frac zk\right)\right],
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Then:
$$\Phi(z):=\frac{\log\Gamma(1+z)}z=
-\gamma+\sum_{k\ge1}\left[\frac 1k-\frac1z\log\left(1+\frac zk\right)\right].\tag1
$$

Differentiating the equation $(1)$ over $z$ one obtains:
$$
\frac{d\Phi(z)}{dz}
=\frac1{z^2}\sum_{k\ge1}\left[\log\left(1+\frac zk\right)-\frac z{z+k}\right]>0.\tag2
$$
(The proof that all summands are positive is left as a simple exercise.)

From $(2)$ one concludes:
$$z_1<z_2\implies\Phi(z_1)<\Phi(z_2)
$$
which in turn means:
$$
\frac{\log\Gamma(1+z_1)}{z_1}<\frac{\log\Gamma(1+z_2)}{z_2}
\implies z_2\log\Gamma(1+z_1)<z_1\log\Gamma(1+z_2)\\
\implies (z_1!)^{z_2}<(z_2!)^{z_1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

By Stirling's approximation

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$

$$\implies (n!)^m \sim \sqrt{(2 \pi n)^m}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{nm} \quad (m!)^n=\sqrt{(2 \pi m)^n}\left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^{nm}$$

and

$$\frac{(m!)^n}{(n!)^m}=\frac1{(2\pi)^{m-n}}\left(\frac{m^n}{n^m}\right)\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{nm}=\frac1{(2\pi n)^{m-n}}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n(m+1)}$$

and by $m=n+k$

$$\frac{(m!)^n}{(n!)^m}=\frac1{(2\pi n)^{k}}\left(1+\frac k n\right)^{n(n+k+1)}$$

which seems to have a minimum greater than $1$ for $k=1$.